# Safari unable to open Angular app served on a different port

Tags: angular, webstorm, liveserver

I am facing an issue with Safari when trying to open my Angular app served on a different port. The Angular app is running successfully on my PC using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4210`. However, when I try to access it from Safari on my iPhone using the URL `http://192.168.10.104:4210/`, Safari reports that the server has stopped responding.

##### Details:

I have confirmed that the Angular development server is running. The firewall settings allow incoming connections on port 4210. The iPhone is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the PC. I use WebStorm IDE.

Command used to start the Angular server:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4210
```

My IP on my PC is :

```text
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.104
```

I want to live-preview my Angular app on my iPhone for the responsive design.

Comment: can you clarify if using chrome on the iphone works?

Comment: on my pc when i go to http://192.168.56.1:4200/ it works fine , but in my iphone when i go to http://192.168.56.1:4200/ in safary nor in the google chrome it dose not work

Comment: what is the wifi ipv4 submask? What is the iphone ip address? What is the LAN submask?

Comment: the submasks are 255.255.255.0 and the ip of teh iphoen is 192.168.10.102

Comment: okay the iphone appears to be on the same network based on the subnet. but you need to use address of the WLAN adapter http://192.168.10.104:4210. and you state that the port is 4210.

Comment: @arentalb check out you are using different portts... In OP you talk about 4210 while you say it works on port 4200. Just get your ports straight so we make sure it isn't just a port mistake. Have you also checked firewall settings? Windows users reported having to be on a private network for it to work.